# Combine POSIXct columns indicating start and end of a marker

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I have my main data `df`, and a separate data frame `df_marker` that indicate the **start** and **end** of a marker. My `df` data frame is second by second, and in a `POSIXct` format. I would like to join `df_marker` into `df` and be able to display the marker on every second within **start** and **end**.

**reprex:**

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  date = as.POSIXct(c("2020-11-17 12:00:00", "2020-11-17 12:00:01", "2020-11-17 12:00:02", "2020-11-17 12:00:03", "2020-11-17 12:00:04", "2020-11-17 12:00:05"))
)

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   date               
#>   <dttm>             
#> 1 2020-11-17 12:00:00
#> 2 2020-11-17 12:00:01
#> 3 2020-11-17 12:00:02
#> 4 2020-11-17 12:00:03
#> 5 2020-11-17 12:00:04
#> 6 2020-11-17 12:00:05

df_marker <- tibble(
  start = as.POSIXct("2020-11-17 12:00:02"),
  end = as.POSIXct("2020-11-17 12:00:05"),
  marker = "marker_1"
)

df_marker
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   start               end                 marker  
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>   
#> 1 2020-11-17 12:00:02 2020-11-17 12:00:05 marker_1
```

This is my **expected output:**

```r
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   date                marker  
#>   <dttm>              <chr>   
#> 1 2020-11-17 12:00:00 <NA>    
#> 2 2020-11-17 12:00:01 <NA>    
#> 3 2020-11-17 12:00:02 marker_1
#> 4 2020-11-17 12:00:03 marker_1
#> 5 2020-11-17 12:00:04 marker_1
#> 6 2020-11-17 12:00:05 marker_1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df_marker %>% mutate(date = map2(start, end, `:`)) %>% unnest(date) %>% 
mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, origin = '1970-01-01')) %>% select(3,4) %>% 
right_join(df) %>% arrange(date) %>% select(2,1)
Joining, by = "date"
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  date                marker  
  <dttm>              <chr>   
1 2020-11-17 12:00:00 NA      
2 2020-11-17 12:00:01 NA      
3 2020-11-17 12:00:02 marker_1
4 2020-11-17 12:00:03 marker_1
5 2020-11-17 12:00:04 marker_1
6 2020-11-17 12:00:05 marker_1
```

For minute by minute:

```
library(lubridate)
df
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  date               
  <dttm>             
1 2020-11-17 12:00:00
2 2020-11-17 12:01:01
3 2020-11-17 12:02:02
4 2020-11-17 12:03:03
5 2020-11-17 12:04:04
6 2020-11-17 12:05:05
df_marker
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  start               end                 marker  
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>   
1 2020-11-17 12:01:02 2020-11-17 12:03:05 marker_1
df_marker %>% mutate(across(start:end, ~ round_date(., unit = '1 minutes'))) %>% 
mutate(date = map2(start, end, `:`)) %>% unnest(date) %>% 
mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, origin = '1970-01-01')) %>% select(3,4) %>% 
right_join(df %>% mutate(date = round_date(date, unit = '1 minutes'))) %>% 
arrange(date) %>% select(2,1)
Joining, by = "date"
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  date                marker  
  <dttm>              <chr>   
1 2020-11-17 12:00:00 NA      
2 2020-11-17 12:01:00 marker_1
3 2020-11-17 12:02:00 marker_1
4 2020-11-17 12:03:00 marker_1
5 2020-11-17 12:04:00 NA      
6 2020-11-17 12:05:00 NA
```

Comment: any suggestions on how to do the same for minute by minute?

Comment: @FMM, have updated my answer to include minute by minute, please check if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the great answer from Karthik S, you can also try `interval()` for `df_marker` and later `%within%` to check any of date from `df` are within this time interval.

These two functions are from `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)

df_marker <- df_marker %>%
  mutate(interval = interval(start,end))

  start               end                 marker    interval
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>     <interval>
1 2020-11-17 12:01:02 2020-11-17 12:03:05 marker_1  2020-11-17 12:01:00 CET--2020-11-17 12:03:00 CET

df <- df %>%
  mutate(marker = ifelse(date %within% df_marker$interval,
                         df_marker$marker, NA))

> df
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  date                marker  
  <dttm>              <chr>   
1 2020-11-17 12:00:00 NA      
2 2020-11-17 12:01:01 NA      
3 2020-11-17 12:02:02 marker_1
4 2020-11-17 12:03:03 marker_1
5 2020-11-17 12:04:04 NA      
6 2020-11-17 12:05:05 NA      
7 2020-11-17 12:06:06 NA
```

For minute by minute, grab `round_date()` around interval and date columns from both tables. This function also comes from `lubridate` package.

```
df_marker <- df_marker %>%
  mutate(interval = interval(round_date(start,"minute"), round_date(end,"minute")))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(marker = ifelse(round_date(date, "minute") %within% df_marker$interval,
                         df_marker$marker, NA))
> df
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  date                marker  
  <dttm>              <chr>   
1 2020-11-17 12:00:00 NA      
2 2020-11-17 12:01:01 marker_1
3 2020-11-17 12:02:02 marker_1
4 2020-11-17 12:03:03 marker_1
5 2020-11-17 12:04:04 NA      
6 2020-11-17 12:05:05 NA
```